# Can events be emitted WITHOUT a transaction?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, transactions, events

I am curious as to why the emission of Ethereum events is tethered to the fact of a transaction being entirely mined

I realize that we can also make calls to `public view functions`, which do NOT require a transaction to be called in the Smart Contract

Can such functions result in events being emitted ?

Answer (score 2):

Nope events cannot be emitted without transaction. until or unless you don't do any transaction they will not emit. basically they store data free

in case of **public view functions** they are simply the read functions (which cost not gas fee ) which retrieve the information stores on the blockchain. therefore we don't use events inside read functions.
https://betterprogramming.pub/what-is-an-event-in-solidity-420caeb38859